# How to access a symbol defined in nested module?

Tags: rust

I am using rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)

```
src
├── main.rs
└── core
    ├── mod.rs
    └── expressionType.rs
```

main.rs:

```
mod core;
use core::expressionType;

fn main() {
    let t = expressionType::ExpressionType.Integer;
    println!("Hello, world!")
}
```

expressionType.rs:

```
pub enum ExpressionType {
    Integer,
    List(Box<ExpressionType>),
    Function(Box<ExpressionType>, Box<ExpressionType>)
}
```

mod.rs:

```
pub mod expressionType;
```

from src, when I try to do rustc main.rs, I get

```
main.rs:5:13: 5:43 error: unresolved name `expressionType::ExpressionType`
main.rs:5     let t = expressionType::ExpressionType.Integer;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I also tried core::expressionType::ExpressionType and expressionType.ExpressionType

Am I missing something? Why can't I access enum from expressionType.rs

UPD1: I also tried to add

```
pub use self::expressionType::ExpressionType;
```

to mod.rs, but after that in main.rs neither core::ExpressionType, nor expressionType::ExpressionType become available.

Comment: This isn’t how things are done in Rust, by convention; `ExpressionType` should typically not go in a module of its own, it should go straight in the `core` module. Then `core::ExpressionType::Integer`, *&c.* In cases where there’s quite a lot related to that, it might go in a module of its own, but even then it would typically only be exported under `core` directly (`pub enum ExpressionType`, `mod expression_type; pub use expression_type::ExpressionType;`). Also note that module names are snake_case by convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `ExpressionType::Integer` rather than `ExpressionType.Integer` (`::` instead of `.`). In the latter case, the compiler is looking for a value, such as a variable or constant, named `ExpressionType`.

Comment: Gosh, this error description is extremely confusing.

Comment: @LOST: it is rather poor; I expect that the technical reason for it is roughly that it is only looking in the value space, where `ExpressionType` is in the type/module space, so it doesn’t see it at all.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Do you know of any bug report on this issue? I know there is already a bunch of bugs opened regarding improving error messages (such as when a method was not considered because some generic parameter constraint was not met), but I do not know any for this particular "wrong space" issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I do not know of any but I have not searched at all. (Also bear in mind that I can’t remember the jargon for the concepts I refer to precisely, the terms I used are probably not correct.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: wrt jargon: I have the same issue :/